# Gradle, overload extension setter

Tags: groovy, gradle

Given an extension registered in gradle as foo:

```
class Foo {
     Project proj

     void setProject( Project project) {
            this.proj = project
     }

     void setProject( String project) {
            // do stuff
     }
}
```

How do I get:

```
foo {
      project = ':random-project'
}
```

to call the string setter and not fail in setProperty of the decorated extension object due to GroovyCastException?

The reason for this question arose from this issue: https://github.com/Centril/gradle-plugin-robospock/issues/5

Comment: Maybe try `project = project(':random-project')`?

Comment: That is obviously a way to solve it, but it doesn't answer the question... It would be the same as removing a feature...

Comment: Ok. Why to You need to implement it that way? What are You trying to achieve?

Comment: To provide an easier and less verbose DSL to those using my plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luke Daley from Gradleware informed me that this is a limitation of the Groovy language: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2500

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see any better answer yet, I am trying to suggest a possible alternative.

If you can keep type of `proj` as a `String` in `Foo` and where you actually use the instance of `Foo` class, lookup the project using the `findProject` method on the `project` object available to your plugin.

```
class FooPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    // ...
    void apply(Project project) {
        // ...
        project.findProject(fooInstance.proj)
    }
}
```

You may find more on `findProject` or `project` methods to locate a project by path [at API Documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#findProject(java.lang.String))

There might be a way to access current Project instance in your Foo class then you may use the overloaded setter.

Comment: All of these kinds of answers are non-solutions for me..., and I already know that this works... I specifically want to solve this to be able to use the DSL, or to determine that it isn't possible so that I can remove the DSL. Storing it as a String is not something I can do. Tho I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Gradle versions 2.0 and later which is likely due to the move from Groovy 1.x to 2.x. I'd suggest using a later version of Gradle if that is possible.